# ColumnChart not show all string labels

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, column-chart

I have The following problem related with ColumnChart (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart).

If the label (when you mouse hover into any columns that looks like a tooltip) is set as a number, all 2000 items shows correctly. But if the label is set as a string it only shows 289 items in the chart and it is missing 1711 columns for an unknown reason.

I have this code (Label set with String, only shows 289 items instead of 2000):
http://jsfiddle.net/c809mbjx/11/

```js
function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string' ,'Day');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Matches');
    var dataArray = []
    let number = 2000
    data.addRows(number);
    for (var i = 0; i < number;i++) {
     data.setCell(i,0,"aaa_"+i)
     data.setCell(i,1,i);
    }
    //var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);        
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        view.setColumns([0, 1]);
    var options = {
            colors: ['#0095e8'],
            hAxis: {textPosition: 'none'},
            vAxis: {minValue: 0, viewWindow: {min: 0}},
            legend: 'none',
            animation: {duration: 10000, easing: 'out'}
        };
    chart.draw(view, options);
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
```

And this code (Label set with Number and works correctly):
http://jsfiddle.net/c809mbjx/12/

```js
function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number' ,'Day');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Matches');
    var dataArray = []
    let number = 2000
    data.addRows(number);
    for (var i = 0; i < number;i++) {
     data.setCell(i,0,i)
     data.setCell(i,1,i);
    }
    //var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);        
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        view.setColumns([0, 1]);
    var options = {
            colors: ['#0095e8'],
            hAxis: {textPosition: 'none'},
            vAxis: {minValue: 0, viewWindow: {min: 0}},
            legend: 'none',
            animation: {duration: 10000, easing: 'out'}
        };
    chart.draw(view, options);
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
```

Comment: Hi @WhiteHat I refered to tooltip when mouse hover in each column..and not show all data in the chart

Comment: looks like a limitation of the chart, if I increase the width of the chart, more columns are shown, but still not all. why do you want to use string instead of number? we can probably find a workaround for the reason while using numbers...

Comment: hi @WhiteHat , I need use the string because.. each columns represents a date ( 01-02-2021).. and only can use this tooltip label.. but for example with Linear Chart works correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/qzgo2rn5/

I think that is a bug for ColumnChart .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use numbers on the x-axis and still display the string on the tooltip.
which can be accomplished by setting the last argument of the `setCell` method --> `formattedValue`

```
setCell(rowIndex, columnIndex, value, formattedValue)
```

the tooltip will display the formatted value by default.
so we provide the number as the value, and our own string as the formatted value.

```
   data.setCell(i,0,i,"aaa_"+i);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number' ,'Day');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Matches');
  let number = 2000;
  data.addRows(number);
  for (var i = 0; i < number;i++) {
   data.setCell(i,0,i,"aaa_"+i);
   data.setCell(i,1,i);
  }
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1]);
  var options = {
    colors: ['#0095e8'],
    hAxis: {textPosition: 'none'},
    vAxis: {minValue: 0, viewWindow: {min: 0}},
    legend: 'none',
    animation: {duration: 10000, easing: 'out'}
  };
  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

---

note: the version of google charts loaded using `jsapi` has been deprecated and should no longer be used.

instead, use `loader.js`, this will only change the load statement.
see above snippet...